# AJAX - jQuery vs direct XmlHttpRequest returnning script oddness

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get to the bottom of some oddness between doing AJAX with jQuery vs. manipulating XmlHttpRequest directly. The test case I've got below is classic ASP, but that's only my convienence - server-side technology shouldn't matter.

I ought to add that I've not excluded stupidity on my part -- I'm just not sure what it is :-) This may be completely trivial and I'm missing something fairly obvious, but I'm not getting my google-fu correct to actually find out what it is I'm missing.

Essentially I'm calling code that returns inline Javascript. This is injected into the HTML page, and is intended to be executed. I have full control over all the code and the server (i.e., this should not be cross-domain request).

What I'm seeing is that the jQuery version works - it executes the script returned by the AJAX page. The direct method doesn't work. The javascript does not execute.

My first thought was "XSS", and that jQuery did something specific to the headers, however I've investigated with fiddler and, I see both requests going out, both return the same code. I've also got both requests to mirror exactly, with the exception of the `GET` (jQuery sticks a querystring on the request - I assume this is to get around caching issues), but in essence the request looks like this:

```
GET http://myLocalMachine:8000/ajaxtest/ajax.asp HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-gb
Referer: http://hsl10161:8000/ajaxtest/main.html
Accept: text/html, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.3; MATM)
Host: myLocalMachine:8000
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

...note that there is no Access-Control header in the request, nor is any returned in the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: No-cache
Pragma: No-cache
Content-Type: text/html
Expires: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 10:00:57 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-UA-Compatible: IE=EmulateIE7
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2012 10:01:57 GMT
Content-Length: 55
```

The rest of this content is a test case...the behaviour described occurs on IE8 and Firefox 10.

**ajax.asp**

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Option Explicit
Response.CacheControl = "No-cache"
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "No-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
%>
<script type="text/javascript">alert('Hi!');</script>
```

**main.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function resetdiv()
        {
            $('#target').html('...');
        }
    </script>
    <title>AJAX test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="target"></div>
    <button onclick="ajax1('ajax.asp', 'target')">With jQuery</button>
    <button onclick="ajax2('ajax.asp', 'target')">Without jQuery</button>
    <button onclick="resetdiv();">Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.js**

```
function ajax1(strURL,target)
{
$.ajax({
    url: strURL,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    type: "GET",
    success: function (data) {
        $('#' + target).html(data);
    }
});
}

function ajax2(strURL,target)
{
var localAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
localAjax.open("GET", strURL, false);
localAjax.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html, */*");
localAjax.setRequestHeader("x-requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");
localAjax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (localAjax.readyState == 4)
    {
        var respText = localAjax.responseText;
        var targetField = document.getElementById(target);
        if (targetField != null) {
            targetField.innerHTML = respText;
        }
    }
}
localAjax.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery executes the code added to the DOM when its added using `.html()`... JavaScript `.innerHTML` does not. You could use the `eval()` function on your code to cause it to execute

Comment: Ta ... I had a feeling it was going to be something insanely obvious but couldn't figure out what it was I was missing.